# Storing Cart in local storage and persisting Data on route change vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, local-storage

I have a cart that clears each time I change my route and I'd like to persist this cart even if I change my route. I am using watch to render the products on route change. I can successfully Add the cart product to LocalStorage, but when I change my route and add products from a different category, the localStorage clears. How can I persist my cart via localStorage?
Here is my code:

```
    addTocart: function (product) {
          this.cartProducts.push(product)
          console.log(this.cartProducts)
          this.showCart = true
// successfuly added to localStorage
          window.localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(this.cartProducts))
        },
```

Loading the products on url change

```
watch: {
    '$route.params.categoryId': function (id) {
      this.getProducts()
// I am trying to get the cart from localStorage at this point
      this.cartProducts = window.localStorage.getItem('cart')
      console.log(this.cartProducts)
    }
  },
```

How can I access my cart from local storage even when I add products from a different route?

Comment: I can't speak to the route part, but localStorage isn't path-specific. This line is incorrect, though: `this.cartProducts = window.localStorage.getItem('cart')`. You need a `JSON.parse` in there: `this.cartProducts = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('cart'))`. (Also note that the `window.` part of `window.localStorage` is unnecessary unless you have an unfortunately-named variable shadowing the global `localStorage`.)

Comment: I would suggest to not use localstorage to manage the cart, but Vuex instead. It is something more to learn, but I think it is worth it.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon - Does Vuex persist the state across page reloads / leaving the page and coming back the next day? (I didn't see anything about doing so on https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/ and a search of the domain didn't turn up matches for `localStorage`, but...)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder No, it does not. You configure it to load from the `localstorage` and save in it on update, but you don't need to *hack* the `vue-router` to keep your data between components, hence why I suggested to use it. Of course, you'll still need `localstorage` if you want your cart to persist between sessions and reload. I was not recommending `vuex`to solve his issue, but to enhance (imo) his workflow.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon - Thanks!